# Is there any way to Install and Boot windows xp "or any other version" on usb flash disk

Tags: windows

I have a computer with broken hard drive .. 
I can not get a new drive right now .. 
So , Can I install windows on an 8GB usb disk and boot from it ..or copy an installed windows to a flash disk and boot this windows from it..  and how?

Comment: You can, just as to the fact that it outright breaks the Windows EULA.

Comment: @TD.512: Are you sure? I seem to recall caveat in EULA about installing XP on "storage devices"...  Also, it's still the workstation that has been licensed, not the HDD...

Comment: exactly, meaning that if OP were to move XP to a different PC, the EULA would be broken. and to both answers: without severe registry hacking, there is no way to install XP TO a drive, only to install XP FROM a pendrive

Comment: Can I copy an installed  windows xp system from a hard drive to an usb flash disk so I can run it witout hard drive ..

Comment: @JackRIDE - Read TD.512's comment again.

Comment: [Yes, but to complicated](https://web.archive.org/web/20071231000131/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176) to reproduce here

Answer (score -1):

You'll need WinToUSB. It's a GUI app that preps a USB key with the necessary boot options and installs Windows from an ISO to it. There's not much that can go wrong.

http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/

There are manual ways of doing it, but this is fast and simple.

Enjoy

Comment: Yep, it does that too. It'll also do what you asked for.

Comment: @Jack RIDE - Don't forget to mark as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If your computer supports USB booting, your can plug a formatted USB into system and run windows XP setup. When you will go to partitioning you will see USB drive. You can install on that USB drive just as you would install on hard drive on your system. I recommend using minimum 16 GB of USB. 32 GB is favorable as you will also have space to install softwares.